# Omitting surrounding <p> being generated from HAML

Tags: html, haml, markdown

Have got the following HAML code, combined with Markdown:

```
%h2.slogan.align-center
  :markdown
    No more big words. Enough of the abbreviations.  
    **Project management for the rest of us.**
```

Which generates HTML:

```
<h2 class='slogan align-center'>
  <p>No more big words. Enough of the abbreviations.<br/>
  <strong>Project management for the rest of us.</strong></p>
</h2>
```

I'd like the HTML to look like (omitting surrounding `<p>` tags):

```
<h2 class='slogan align-center'>
  No more big words. Enough of the abbreviations.<br/>
  <strong>Project management for the rest of us.</strong>
</h2>
```

What's the HAML/Markdown to create that HTML?

Comment: What if you have more than one paragraph block. Do you want them all removed?

Comment: I won't have more than one paragraph block

Comment: @cole-johnson Thanks, how would I go about using regex with HAML and Markdown?

Comment: You don't You never want to use REGEX for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is easy to do with only haml:

```
%h2.slogan.align-center
  No more big words. Enough of the abbreviations.
  %br/
  %strong Project management for the rest of us.
```

It seems like the markdown plugin of haml adds the p tag. According to the [documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter) this is accomplished by using one of 4 different markdown processors. I guess the result may differ depending on which one you are using.

Comment: Tack @froderik, yeah I was hoping to move to a "markdown for marking up content; haml for page layout". I think I'm using `rdiscount` gem.

Comment: methinks haml is nice enough to use for content also rather than mixing the two. Had it been erb I would have been with you all the way.